# How to expand secondary row label within only one primary row label?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Is there a way to expand a secondary row label for only one value of the primary row label?

Before: here are item sales for vendors, with payment terms included.  Each vendor has only one set of payment terms, but may have many items.  So the Pivot Table is rolled up to the Payment Terms level, but the user has the choice to expand a set of Payment Terms to see the items for that vendor.  For this analysis, the Vendor field is left expanded so the user can immediately see payment terms for all vendors.

[image: Pivot 1]

I only want to see items for Company 1, but when I expand its Payment Terms, the Pivot Table also expands the other vendor with the same Payment Terms.

[image: Pivot 2]

I don't want to see Company 4's items, only company 1.  The vendors must be sorted by sales, so flipping the Vendor and Payment Terms fields is not an option.  Additionally, vendors may have 100+ items, so expanding multiple vendors can really alter how the pivot table appears to the user.

I worked around this, by concatenating the vendor name and the payment terms into one field.  But this is not the first time I've run into this scenario, and I'd like to know if Microsoft has a way to prevent this.

**EDIT:** updated example to reflect my actual scenario.

Comment: @pnuts thanks--I wasn't aware of the Super User site.  The images are a simple example of the problem I experienced.  My actual data contains the following row labels: Vendor, Payment Terms, Item Description--and the request asks to see payment terms for each vendor.  I'll add further clarification in the question.